# What are the downsides/pitfalls of NOT using "Whole Program Optimization" /GL and "Link Time Code Generation" /LTCG

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

In my project, which is a framework where performance matters, I am using several static libraries. When building these static libraries, I have two choices for their configuration:

1. Enabling "Whole Program Optimization" `/GL` and "Link Time Code Generation" `/LTCG` and restricting the release build of my framework to being used (out of the box) with one specific version of platform toolset (let's say "Visual Studio 2017 (v141)"). Trying to build the framework in Visual Studio 2019 (v142) using the v141 pre-built libraries, results in an error message like *"[...]was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries"* for the release build. The only option here is to re-build the libraries with v142, but then they can't be used with v141 anymore.
2. Disabling `/GL` and `/LTCG` for the libraries which has the effect that they can be used with many different platform toolsets, i.e. v141, v142 and others.

My question is: Does the second option have any downsides or hidden pitfalls, or is it a valid way? What if there are huge amounts of calls into the libraries during run-time? Can there be performance issues?

Comment: LTCG is a performance enhancing feature (a lot for some programs, very little for other programs). The downside of not using it is that you don't get the performance improvement that it can bring.

Comment: What kind of performance improvements could that be? Code that can be inlined with LTCG or something like that?